# Use du command on files only

Tags: shell

How can I make this command run on files only?

```
du -h * | sort -h -r | head -n 5
```

Now I am using * which runs on all files and directories but I want to change that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the `find` utility to pinpoint only the files:

```
find . -type f -exec du -h {} + | sort -n -r | head -n 5
```

also you have a typo, it's `sort -n -r` not `sort -h -r`

Comment: "also you have a typo, it's sort -n -r not sort -h -r" That's a flag in GNU `sort`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html.

Comment: The `{}` placeholder needs single quotes like `'{}'` to deal with file names that have embedded spaces and other whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps

```
for i in $(ls -d */ | sort -h -r | head -n 5); do du -h $i; done
```